# Using filter:opacity to create two versions of a color in the same element

Tags: css

I am trying to define a CSS class that creates two versions of a color in the same element using `filter:opacity(25%)`. (I am aware that this solution won't work in Internet Explorer.)

The problem is that the filter and non-filter versions of the color can't be used at the same time.

Here is a Codepen that shows my attempt and hopefully illustrates what I am trying to do.

https://codepen.io/timmerbu/pen/ZEBLNKa

```css
:root {
    --custom: #9400d3; /* single definition */
}
.bubble { padding:.5rem; margin-bottom:.25rem; border-radius:.25rem; } /* not part of solution */
text-custom {
    color:var(--custom) !important;
}
.bg-custom, .btn-custom, .badge-custom {
    background-color:var(--custom) !important;
    border-color:var(--custom);
}
.table-custom, .alert-custom {
    background-color:var(--custom);
    filter:opacity(25%);
}
.alert.alert-custom {
    color:var(--custom);
    border-color:var(--custom) !important;
}
label { font-weight:600; } /* not part of solution */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container pt-3">
    <p>Objective: Use a color defined by a <strong>single</strong> hex triplet to create a two-color Bootstrap style alert box:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Text color: Hex triplet,</li>
        <li>Background color: Hex triplet with <code>filter:opacity(25%)</code>,</li>
        <li>Border: Hex triplet.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Problem: Can't get main and light versions of hex triplet to work at the same time in the <code>alert.alert-custom</code> class.
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Primary</label>
            <div class="bubble bg-primary"></div>
            <div class="bubble table-primary"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-primary">Alert</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Secondary</label>
            <div class="bubble bg-secondary"></div>
            <div class="bubble table-secondary"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-secondary">Alert</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Danger</label>
            <div class="bubble bg-danger"></div>
            <div class="bubble table-danger"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">Alert</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Warning</label>
            <div class="bubble bg-warning"></div>
            <div class="bubble table-warning"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">Alert</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Info</label>
            <div class="bubble bg-info"></div>
            <div class="bubble table-info"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-info">Alert</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Success</label>
            <div class="bubble bg-success"></div>
            <div class="bubble table-success"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-success">Alert</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Custom</label>
            <div class="bubble bg-custom"></div>
            <div class="bubble table-custom"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-custom">Alert</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include you code here on StackOverflow. There is an option when you edit your question to "insert code snippet." If the codepen link you provided ever goes down, then this question becomes useless to future readers. Thank you.

Comment: use sass to make it dynamic using sass variables and functions like ```rgba()```

Comment: @AbdelmonaemShahat Yep. I'm aware I could sass or even simpler just hardcode the triplet for the light version, but I'm still hoping for a freaky clever CSS only solution.